# Why shouldn't I use function-like macros with not constant variables

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor, latency

I'm making some computations for an animation and wanted to make a simple global formula which I could use throughout my code. So I made a function-like macro. In this macro I have various input-types (int,float) and a double-type as a result. Now, it works - but it's a whole lot slower as just declaring the formulas when they're needed.
The animation is screened with xlib functions.

Example:
Usage of a global function-like macro function for computation (slow):

```
int x=0,y=0;
float  angle=0;
#define A(x,y) (x*sin(angle) - y*cos(angle))

int main(){

while(1){
...display picture_buffer with xlib-functions...
//compute picture_buffer:
   for(x; x < picture_width; x++){
       for(y; y < picture_height; y++){
            picture_buffer = A(x,y) ;
       }
     }
   }
}
```

How does the program access 'precompiled' values which are variating?

Before, I've used a function-like macro with just int-types doing modulo operation with them. In that case I could not recognize any significant latency.

Comment: You could use a `static inline` function instead of the macro since you're using GCC.  You should pass the `angle` as an argument to the macro/function rather than relying on a global (it complicates the code analysis when you use a global; it may also slow things down since a global can't be placed in a register).  Since `angle` is a `float`, consider using `sinf()` and `cosf()` rather than incurring the cost of converting the global variable into a `double` before calling the trig functions each time.

Comment: Using a macro should have exactly zero effect on performance relative to using the equivalent code directly.